# Как отсортировать вложенный (?) массив?

Tags: массивы, сортировка, php

Есть массив типа:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [version] => 4.9.633
        [name] => File Service
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [version] => 5.3.566.1
        [name] => File Service 5
    )
)
```

Как средствами PHP отсортировать его по значению version (например, по возрастанию)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добро пожаловать в сладкий мир [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

```
usort(
    $array,
    function($a, $b) {
        if ($a['version'] == $b['version']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return $a['version'] < $b['version'] ? -1 : 1;
    }
);
```