# Как отсортировать двухмерный массив по значению элемента

Tags: php

Друзья, у меня массив такой структуры:

```
["5193","3096","50000","6.2"]]
[["2213","6857.82","100000","6.9"],
```

Мне необходимо отсортировать массив согласно значению последнего элемента в каждом подмассиве по убыванию. Т.е. согласно значению 6.2 и 6.9 После сортировки я по сути должен получить вот такой массив:

```
[["2213","6857.82","100000","6.9"],
["5193","3096","50000","6.2"]]
```

Как это сделать? Я читал про функцию usort, но не совсем могу понять как она работает и как мне сделать сортировку в моем конкретном случае

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php

Comment: спасибо про функцию в курсе. Возможно вы можете помочь готовым кодом как это реализовать с помощью данной функции?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отсортировать вложенный (?) массив?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/359642/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array=[...];
usort($array, function($a,$b){return end($a) < end($b);})
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

```
$arr = [["5193","3096","50000","6.2"], ["2213","6857.82","100000","6.9"]];

usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return end($a) < end($b);
});
```